# Rails: uniqueness validation using array for scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, scope, rails-models

I'm doing a `tags` model where one of the attributes is the `title` of the tag. The goal is that there will be articles that can be tagged by a predefined set of topics:

```
TOPICS = ['Politics', 'Art', 'Sports', 'Tech', 'Business', 'Science']
```

I would like to create a uniqueness validation such that whenever a tag is assigned to an article, its `title` must be any of the elements in `TOPICS`. Can I do this via the following?

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :uniqueness => { :scope => TOPICS }
end
```

If not, how do I set `TOPICS` as the scope for `title`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates :title, inclusion: TOPICS
```

or

```
validates_inclusion_of :title, in: TOPICS
```